# Using \include format of the main text changes

Tags: formatting

The format in **chapter 1** has no problem at all, but when I **include** in the main text, the format changed.

This is the chapter 1,preambles:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
```

This is in the main text preambles, I used
`\include{Chapters/Chapter1}`:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{report}%letter and artcile type
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

In the main text, I used preambles and in the chapter 1 I used preambles too, is this the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please don't post pictures of code, but trim your code down to a minimal example that you think should work.  But it looks like your included file has its own `\documentclass`.  That's not what you want.  Basically, `\include` acts as if the contents of the file were pasted into that spot (surrounded by pagebreaks).  Since you can't have a second `\documentclass`, you can't have that in an included file.  (If you really want to go that route, look into the subfiles package.)

Comment: you can not `\include` a file with `\documentclass` there can only be one preamble for the whole document

Comment: Welcome. // Perhaps there are some misconceptions about the preamble. E.g.: a) there can only be one, b) having more packages than needed most of the time doesn't cause problems, c) to reuse preambles for a given documentclass, e.g. to compile subchapters separately, please have a look at package `subfiles`, e.g. here: https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf . For more details on Latex this is quite a good place to look things up: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\include` acts as if the contents of the file were pasted into that spot (surrounded by pagebreaks).  This means that your main file is acting like:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
% chapter 1:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
Chapter 1
\end{document} 
% end chapter 1
\end{document}
```

Since you can't have a second `\documentclass`, you can't have that in an included file.

If you really want to be able to compile chapters on their own, look into the subfiles package.  But it's usually easier to have `chapter1.tex` just have the content for chapter 1, and then if you only want to compile chapter 1, you can have `\includeonly{chapter1}` in your (main file's) preamble.  Your main file would end up looking like:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
% other preamble material
% \includeonly{Chapters/Chapter1} % optional
\begin{document}
\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
\end{document}
```

and a chapter file would look like

```tex
\chapter{Chapter 1 Title}
Chapter 1 content
```

The idea of `\includeonly` is if you have several different chapters that you've included, then you can use `\includeonly` to make only a few of them actually included.  TeX will use the counters from the non-included files so that the included  material still has the right numbering, but now you can have a much faster compilation because you don't need to compile the non-included files.

Comment: Thank you, should I remove the \documentclass in the chapter files and put \includeonly{chapter1} in the preambles in the main file? I tried, but it doesn't load the chapter 1.

Comment: the chapter files should start `\chapter{...}` no `\documentclass` or `\usepackage`  then in the body of your main document (not the preamble) include a chapter with `\include{Chapters/Chapter1}`  @happyanyland

Comment: @happyanyland I've added an example of how it would work.

Comment: if I remove the preambles in the chapters, the chapter can not be compiled any more. I don't know what is happened.

Comment: I finally know what you mean, I tried and it works! Thanks you all for the help.